# Puzzle: what does this bash command do?

Tags: bash

Found this in `https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml` and I'm really puzzled with what this command actually does. Can anyone enlighten me?

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    npm test && s=0 && break || s=$? && sleep 1
done
(exit $s)
```

Comment: From [tag:puzzle] tag info page: "DO NOT USE - prefer constructive questions, or use more descriptive tags. Otherwise, your question might be appropriate for codegolf.stackexchange.com."

Comment: It attempts to run `npm` command 5 times and exits with exit status of `npm` at first success or 5 failures.

Comment: @anubhava **Avoid answering questions in comments.**

Comment: As a question this should be too broad (there are a lot of commands and symbols there. What do you need explaining?

Comment: What is the use of the parenthesis in `(exit $s)`? If I do `(echo hello)` and `echo hello` I get the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer as suggested.

This script attempts to run `npm test` command maximum 5 times and exits with exit status of `npm` at the first success or 5 failures. For each failed attempt it sleeps for `1` second before next attempt.

This script may be rewritten as (for understanding):

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++)); do
    if npm test; then
       s=0
       break
    else
       s=$?
       sleep 1
    fi
done
exit $s
```